# Overriding style of antd Button using styled components is not working?

Tags: reactjs, antd, styled-components

```
import styled from 'styled-components';
import { Button } from 'antd';

const StyledButton = styled(Button)`
  height: 100%;
  border-width: 0px;
  &:hover {
    color: palevioletred;
    border-color: red;
  }
`;

export default StyledButton;
```

Overriding style of antd Button component is not working?

Answer (score 0):

I just take your code and it overrides the style of antd correctly. There may be some other reason